# image button is not working properly

Tags: android

In my project i included a new feature like sharing the snapshot of my app. while running my project in my device the feature not working while clicking my `Button` it didn't do anything simply it shows **Logcat** like this    :
how can i solve it..???

thank you in advance

```
08-04 16:08:33.059  32052-32062/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.343ms
08-04 16:08:33.115  32052-32062/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 49.947ms
08-04 16:08:33.122  32052-32067/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 146699(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 57(1824KB) LOS objects, 18% free, 34MB/42MB, paused 1.590ms total 279.950ms
08-04 16:08:33.139  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:08:33.772  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:08:36.134  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:08:41.027  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:08:41.842  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:08:42.564  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:08:43.788  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:08:44.504  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:08:46.948  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:08:51.777  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:08:52.490  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:08:53.209  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:08:54.572  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:08:55.359  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:08:57.612  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:02.531  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:03.243  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:04.075  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:05.189  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:06.110  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:08.265  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:13.177  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:13.996  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:14.107  32052-32067/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 92885(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 23(368KB) LOS objects, 16% free, 35MB/42MB, paused 1.240ms total 111.681ms
08-04 16:09:14.718  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:15.847  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:16.762  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:18.912  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:23.825  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:24.646  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:25.363  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:26.516  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:27.521  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:29.563  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:34.486  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:35.397  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:36.215  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:37.349  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:38.168  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:40.415  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:45.124  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-04 16:09:46.050  32052-32052/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/aagr_background2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/adview153613"
        android:name="com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragadmob" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/aanavigationbar">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_x="8px"
            android:layout_y="3px"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_breaker_bay"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="437dp"
            android:layout_y="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add11_table"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/back"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="30px"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/back"
            android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
            android:background="@drawable/home1"
            android:paddingBottom="12px"
            android:paddingTop="10px"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:background="@drawable/share"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.11"
        android:background="@drawable/stag"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.91"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >



        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/table"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="48dp"
            android:layout_y="4dp"
            android:text="Line"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="128dp"
            android:layout_y="4dp"
            android:text="circle"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="212dp"
            android:layout_y="4dp"
            android:text="vshape"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </AbsoluteLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code for button

```
    public class Engagement_Tableviewtable extends FragmentActivity
{
    Bitmap myBitmap;
    Button button;
     @Override
      public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
       // The rest of your onStart() code.
        // //  EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);  // Add this method.
      }

      @Override
      public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // The rest of your onStop() code.
        // EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);  // Add this method.
      }


    ImageButton tshape;
     int totadlcnt = 0;

    LinearLayout layout1;

    LinearLayout table;

    LinearLayout mylayout;

    int status;
    String tablecnt= null;
    String username=LoginForm.str1;
    private String result = null;
    StringTokenizer2 token = null, token1 = null,token2 =null;
    ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> value1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> totseat=null;
    ArrayList<String> shape = null; 
    ArrayList<String> tblcount = null;
    ArrayList<String> totadltseats = null;
    ArrayList<String> adultcnt = null;
    ArrayList<String> totkidseats = null;
    ArrayList<String> kidcnt = null;
    ArrayList<String> tottno = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> clo = new ArrayList<String>();
     ScrollView scroll;
    static int NO_OF_ROWS =5;

    String occation = SeatingArrangement.funName;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(this, "68640bea");

            setContentView(R.layout.seat);

           Button back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
            Button home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                button();
            }
        });
     public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "Pictures/screenshot.png";
        File imagePath = new File(filePath);
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            sendMail(filePath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public void sendMail(String path) {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("image/png");
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    }

    private boolean button() {
        final FrameLayout iv = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.vg);
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        // View v1 = iv.getRootView(); //even this works
        // View v1 = findViewById(android.R.id.content); //this works too
        // but gives only content
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        myBitmap = v1.getDrawingCache();
        saveBitmap(myBitmap);

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Any chance of seeing some code?

Comment: yes which code u need xml or java

Comment: https://vaibhavtolia.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/79/

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
write `saveBitmap()` in seperate thread.

```
Thread tr = new Thread(){
run(){
saveBitmap();

}
}

tr.start();
```

I think, Your problem with loading too much thing with main thread.

I guess button click is,

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                button();
            }
        });
```

check that also.

Comment: where should i place it

Comment: In place where you are calling saveBitmap();, you can replace that with this code.

Comment: You can check the basic click() function by commenting the remaining functionality and test whether it works or not.